# Mongoose select everything in a list

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got this array of usernames ['user1','user2'] and I want to query information about these users.

I thought

```
User.find({userName : users}, function(err, results) {
        callback(results);
});
```

would work, but it only works when there is 1 user in the array.(ex. ['user1'])

Is it even possible to do something like that, or should I do a query for every user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do an IN query so it matches what's inside the array. haven't test this, but something similar to this is what you're looking for:

```
User.find({userName : {$in: users}}, function(err, results) {
        callback(results);
});
```